# Creating a socket C++

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket

I'm fairly new here and I'm trying to test my own sockets program.

How would one create a socket? Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int socket_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[100], server_message[100];

    // Creates the socket
    socket_addr = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_addr == -1) {
        cout << "Could not create the socket!";
    } else {
    //...
    }
}
```

EDIT: These two links helped out a lot on understanding sockets. Please look at them:

```
1) http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/
2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague, try looking around here: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: @Charlie, THANKS! :D

Comment: What's wrong with your code ? what is the error (if an error occured) ? what did you expect as behavior and which one do you get ?

Comment: That code looks fine except you should close your if statement with a `)`

Comment: @Garf365, Well, I was following a tutorial online and did this exact step. Compiled and ran it and the message above in the cout statement came up... so I'm assuming a socket wasn't created? How would you be able to create that socket?

Comment: You should call `WSAStartup` first before trying to do any socket operations.

Comment: @GillBates, Could you give me an code example?

Comment: The [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx) on the documentation website says enough.

Comment: @Johnson Are you on windows or on another OS?

Comment: @Garf365, I'm on Windows... so I'm assuming no Unix libraries are compatible?

Comment: Right ;) and link provided by Johnson is a good start point. Please, add this information on your title and your question, I think it can help someone else ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you're on windows and I'm assuming the code you showed is the full code the reason it's not working is because of no call to `WSAStartup` has been made yet, this function initializes the network library and should be called before any network operation (like creating a socket):

```
//your includes here..

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") // link with the network library

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int socket_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[100], server_message[100];

    int wsaRes = 0;
    WSADATA wsaData = {0};
    wsaRes = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if(wsaRes != 0)
    {
      std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed!";
      return -1; 
    }
    // Creates the socket
    socket_addr = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_addr == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Could not create the socket!";
    } else {
    //...
    }
}
```